# dom-bind with Polymer 2.0-preview

Tags: binding, polymer, polymer-2.x

I wanted to start to port my Polymer 1.0 application to Polymer 2.0 (preview).

I used `<template is="dom-bind">` in my `index.html` to support data bindings. Is this also possible with Polymer 2? I tried `<dom-bind>` as a component, but it did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Polymer 2.0, make sure to wrap the `<template>` inside `<dom-bind>` as described in the [upgrade guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#remove-type-extension-elements). It's also important to include `polymer.html`, which [imports `dom-bind.html`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/7d4b347/polymer.html#L3) (instead of only `polymer-legacy.html`).

*Polymer 1.0:*

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
  ...
</template>
```

*Polymer 2.0:*

```
<dom-bind id="app">
  <template>
    ...
  </template>
</dom-bind>
```

```js
const app = document.getElementById('app');

app.message = 'Hello world!';
app.counter = 0;

app._onClick = function() {
  this.counter++;
};
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+2.2.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <dom-bind id="app">
    <template>
      <div>[[message]]</div>
      <div>[[counter]]</div>
      <button on-click="_onClick">Increment</button>
    </template>
  </dom-bind>
</body>
```

Comment: @JochenKühner Can you update the question to show the code you've tried?

Comment: It's part of a big project wich I try to convert to polymer 2. But I used the same code as yours in index.html

Comment: @JochenKühner There must be a difference somewhere because the code I've suggested works properly, as demonstrated in the Codepen. It would be helpful to readers to understand what that difference is in order to provide accurate answers. :)

Comment: I included polymer-legacy.html instead of polymer.html

Comment: Glad your problem is solved :) I've updated the answer to include that note.